# Scroll Animation With Text Background

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

Can someone help me with this animation where-in after scrolling to a certain section, the default scroll behavior stops and starts a transition, post which it scrolls.

While coming up, it re-perform the transition and then scrolls up.

I am providing a link to an existing website here the animation exists. It is the fifth section with REFORM CO as the text, the id of the section is 'team'.

Thanks in advance.

Small video of the animation in youtube.
https://youtu.be/CuMJMy9Xb3M

[Animation](https://www.reformcollective.com/)

Comment: The provided link doesn't work (anymore).

Comment: Pleaes check this link - https://youtu.be/CuMJMy9Xb3M      @Abbas